# How to nest column in a column?

Tags: css, grid-layout, semantic-ui

I am using [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/), and when trying to separate a `<div>`, I can get the elements fit in (like the screenshot below):

[image: screen shot]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="ui four column grid">

<div class="column">

    <div class="ui segment">

        <div class="ui top left attached label">Saturday</div>

        <div class="ui two column grid">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="two column"><i class="sunn"></i><i class="cloud"></i></div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="ui statistic">
                    <div class="label">Sun raises</div>
                    <div class="value">06:46</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is a fork:

http://jsfiddle.net/0djhjpym/

Comment: could you provide a complete code, in order to be able to reproduce your problem?

Comment: it is the first div I tested, to learn how to make the right separation of the UI, the CSS is semantic ui css, only the cloud is using http://forecastfont.iconvau.lt/

Comment: Don't do it this way! It only causes headaches!  Instead, you should create a table (class="table") and use rows/columns.  If you need to have multiple columns in one area of the screen and simply one column elsewhere it makes it easy: simply tell the CSS to make the column width a certain amount.  You can do this one of three ways: by pixels, by percentage of the screen used, or by specifying which of the 12 columns to use (i.e. col-span-4).

Comment: @user1789573 this is whay i was doing in the past, without the framework, but I tried to learn this, and wished to do it by the framework way, but it seems that i dident knew how to :(

Comment: You should really specify that in the OP

Comment: @user1789573 I already mentioned that it was using Semantic UI